# Getting  zenity and at to work properly

Tags: linux, terminal, at, zenity

I'm trying to use `zenity` and at to make a little reminder script.  The problem is that while `zenity --info` works fine from `bash` (or `sh`), running `echo "zenity --info" | at now + 1 min` does nothing.  The job shows up in my `atq` and then runs, but no `zenity` pop-up.  What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `/var/log/messages`, chances are you'll have some "Cannot open display" errors from your X Server.

You need to provide utilities like `at` and `cron` access to your X Display by name. Edit your `~/.bashrc` to include the following:

```
xhost local:USERNAME > /dev/null
```

Substitute your username for the `USERNAME` value above. This will provide the `at` utility with the name of your X Display so it can attempt to fork zenity on it.

Modify your zenity command to include the `--display` switch:

```
echo "zenity --info --display=:0.0" | at now + 1 min
```

Comment: Just doing the `--display=:0.0` did it.  Thanks!